# Why are androids in the Alien franchise so fascinated with the alien?

Tags: alien-franchise, alien-1979, aliens-1986, alien-covenant

Why they are so fascinated by the creature? Why do they speak of the xenomorph as being a superior life form?

Comment: Because it's a perfect life-form. Singular, intelligent and deadly.

Comment: I edited the question so it doesn’t refer to “Alien”, as a proper noun, which it isn’t.

Comment: I’m not sure this is a characteristic of androids. Ash and David are into the aliens; Bishop less so. Burke is pretty keen to get some aliens back to earth, so presumably there are also humans with an interest.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The androids are programmed in this way.

Weyland-Yutani, their mother corporation, wants to examine the alien life-form because of its perceived perfection. When, in the first movie, the disabled android on board is brought back online, it confirms that it was placed on board the *Nostromo* specifically to protect the alien life-form in case of contact, and that the human crew is expendable in the agenda of the company.

(Info from the wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ash_(Alien))

Answer (score 3):

Ash (Ian Holm) in the first film comes across as being frustrated by having to deal with humans around the clock. If androids do have feelings just like humans do, then Ash probably feels both inferior and superior to humans. Superior in intelligence and inferior socially, as far as interaction and understanding the subtleties go. I refer to the scene where he tries to choke Ripley to death by basically shoving a rolled up porn mag down her throat. I mean why would he do that? In a cut scene the two women Ripley and Lambert talk about Ash. Ripley ask if Lambert has ever tried to have sex with Ash. Lambert's reply is that he never seemed all that interested.

I would think that part of the fascination that Ash shows for the alien would come from the fact that both Ash and the alien are different from humans, other, truly other. The alien is completely superior to humans. Both physically and intelligence wise at least when it comes to the game of kill or be killed. The alien doesn't have to conform to any social norm. It is what it is.  So the alien is free. Unrestrained. Liberated. To a certain degree Ash has also been the midwife. He has in his lab closely watched what's been happening to Kane.